# Docker image does not start

Tags: docker, liferay, docker-container, docker-image

When I download my Docker image, and try to run it right away, this message appears:

```
/usr/local/bin/liferay_entrypoint.sh: line 41:     8 Killed                  start_liferay.sh
```

The code I use for the run is this:

`docker run -it -m 10g -p 8080:8080 liferay/portal:7.4.3.22-ga22`

but when I put the localhost:8080 in the browser, it goes into infinite looping and does not load

Comment: I have never used the product before, but usually if it gets killed it has some limitations, or application fails to start. Did you check container's logs?. Based on the liferay help site under Interacting with the Container section i found (https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022307392-Leveraging-Docker) that if it gets Killed it usually means you do not have enough memory allocated to your docker engine. Try increasing that?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by lack of ressources allocated to your Docker Engine.
You should increase them is Docker Desktop Setting like follow:
[image]